# Exporting a Swift method that takes a function as parameter to React Native

Tags: ios, swift, objective-c, xcode, react-native

I am trying to export a Swift method that takes a function as parameter to React Native. What I did is as follows:

In `RNMyClass.swift` file:

```
import Foundation

@objc(RNMyClass)
class RNMyClass: NSObject {
  @objc func someMethod(_ successCallback: (String) -> Void) -> Void {
    //Some code goes here...
  }
}
```

In `RNMyClass.m` file:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNMyClass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(someMethod:((*)(NSString *))successCallback)

@end
```

I start the program on iOS simulator by running the following commands:

```
npx react-native start
```

and

```
npx react-native run-ios
```

The code compiles on XCode 13.0 and starts running on iOS simulator 15.0, but when it hits the part where I call this method from react native, the iOS program crashes and the simulator goes to main screen.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that I should have used `RCTResponseSenderBlock` instead of the nasty Swift closure and Objective-C function pointer like so:

```
import Foundation

@objc(RNMyClass)
class RNMyClass: NSObject {
  @objc func someMethod(_ successCallback: RCTResponseSenderBlock) -> Void {
    successCallback([NSNull(), "response from swift"])
  }
}
```

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <React/RCTBridgeModule.h>

@interface RCT_EXTERN_MODULE(RNMyClass, NSObject)

RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(someMethod:(RCTResponseSenderBlock)successCallback)

@end
```

React Native JavaScript code should be like this:

```
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';

NativeModules.RNMyClass.someMethod((err, str) => console.log(str));
```